# How to add a matrix( not the same dimension) below another matrix

Tags: matlab

I know how to add a matrix below another matrix.

e.g A = [A; B];

I have two matrixes of different dimensions(both different number of columns and rows) and i need to add them up together. One matrix is the main one and the other one is being added to it. Both of them are in a for loop and so the dimension of the first matrix is keep changing.

```
e.g for i = 1 :3
      AngerHist = [AngerHist;Hist];
    end
```

When I run it is giving me this error :

```
??? Error using ==> vertcat CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent. –
```

How do i do it? Any suggestions?

```
AngerHist = {}; DisgustHist = {};FearHist = {}; HappyHist = {}; SadHist = {};SurpriseHist = {};
Images = 'C:\Users\HP\Documents\MATLAB\Images';
List = dir(Images);
n= size(List,1);

for i = 3:n
    List1 = dir(fullfile(Images,List(i).name));
    m= size(List1,1);
    BASE_DIR = fullfile(Images,List(i).name);
    for j = 3: m
        I=List1(j).name;
        I1= imread(fullfile(BASE_DIR,I),'jpg');
        Name = List(i).name;
        switch (Name)
                 case 'Anger'
                     Hist = UniformLBP(I1);
                     AngerHist = {AngerHist;Hist};
                     break;
                 case 'Disgust'
                     Hist = UniformLBP(I1);
                     DisgustHist = {DisgustHist;Hist};
                     break;
                case 'Fear'
                    Hist = UniformLBP(I1);
                    FearHist = {FearHist;Hist};
                    break;
                case 'Happy'
                    Hist = UniformLBP(I1);
                    HappyHist = {HappyHist;Hist};
                    break;
                case 'Sad'
                    Hist = UniformLBP(I1);
                    SadHist = {SadHist;Hist};
                    break;
                case 'Surprise'
                    Hist = UniformLBP(I1);
                    SurpriseHist = {SurpriseHist;Hist};
                    break;
        end        

    end    
end
```

Comment: Add two lines of code above what you have in the loop: `size(AngerHist)` and `size(Hist)` (both without semicolons) and tell us what output you see.

Comment: Hist comes from another function..

Comment: Hist  = 1,5901 and AngerHist = 1, 1

Comment: If they have the same number of rows (1 each) you can do horizontal stacking: `AngerHist = [AngerHist Hist];`

Comment: If AngerHist is a row vector as you indictate, you need to concatenate it with Hist row-wise, not column-wise, i.e., 

AngerHist = [AngerHist , Hist];  

Best not to use Hist as a variable name either as hist is the name of a function in MATLAB.

Comment: @mtrw the thing in the first iteration they have the same number of rows but after the second iteration, they change.. not the same anymore

Comment: @Loren Each hist represents features for one image. I am trying to get the features of all the images into a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to use cells:

```
A={};
A=[A;rand(2,3)];
A=[A;rand(3,4)];
A=[A;rand(4,5)];
A=[A;rand(6,5)];
```

The result is:

```
A = 
 [2x3 double]
 [3x4 double]
 [4x5 double]
 [6x5 double]
```

Comment: So use `[]` instead of `{}`, like in my example.

Comment: On the top left corner of each answer, under the score (zero, here), you can tick the answer you think is the best. (It looks like a "V")

Comment: one qn: When u intitalize A, u use {} to say it is a cell array but why do u use [] when u add elements to the cell array?

Comment: That's a good question. When you do [{1},{2}] it gives {1,2}, which is different than {{1},{2}}

Answer (score 2):

To vertically stack two matrices, they must have the same number of columns. For instance:

```
A = rand(3,2);
for ctr = 1:3
    B = rand(4,2);
    A = [A ; B];
end
```

At the end, `A` will be 15x2. Similarly, if the matrices have the same number of rows, you can horizontally stack them.

If the matrices have different numbers of rows and columns, then it does not make sense to use a matrix to represent their collection. You might consider making each matrix an entry in a cell array instead. See [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f4-2137.html#f4-2245) for more information.

Comment: I am having two matrixes. One matrix is the main one and the other one is being added to it. Both of them are in a for loop and so the dimension of the first matrix is keep changing...

Comment: It is giving me this error : ??? Error using ==> vertcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Comment: Do both matrices always have the same number of columns?

Comment: both different rows and columns

Comment: Try `C = {}; for i = 1:3, C = {C A}; end`

Comment: In my code above, the matrix C is Anger Hist. It stops after 2.. meaning to say it is 2 x 1 cell.. it should be definitely higher...

Comment: Your code looks ok, try printing the filenames as it iterates, maybe you'll see your problem.

Comment: i tried in debugging mode.. instead of going from j = 3 to j =4 ,it jumps to n= 3 to 4...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that the matrix size is changing inside the loop. That is allowed. The problem is that to vertically stack two matrices, they each need to have the same number of columns.

Imagine having two matrices:

```
A = [ a b c ;
      d e f ;             
      g h i ]

B = [ q r;
      s t ]
```

and you try to perform:

```
C = [A;B]
```

what dimensions would C have? It's undefined.

You could pad B with a column of zeros (or something) to make it the right width so C would end up looking like:

```
| a b c |
| d e f |
| g h i |
| q r 0 |
| s t 0 |
```

or

```
| a b c |
| d e f |
| g h i |
| 0 q r |
| 0 s t |
```

but that is just a hack to make the matrix stacking operation work.

If the matrices are always different widths you should think about what you're actually trying to do with them and perhaps consider storing them inside a cell array.